# Error when adding Devise gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm trying to add the Devise gem to a Rails app, and I'm getting a weird "no method error" when I try to run `rails g devise:install`. I scanned through all the other Stack posts on it, but none matched my error.

I added the following to my Gemfile:

```
gem 'devise'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-twitter'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'omniauth-linkedin'
```

And ran bundle install. Everything was fine.

Then I tried to install Devise authentication:

```
rails g devise:install

/Users/jake/Documents/Aptana Studio Workspace/
App/config/initializers/assets.rb:5:in `<top (requir
ed)>': undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

...
```

Assets.rb

```
Rails.application.config.assets.version = '1.0'
Rails.application.config.assets.precompilerails  += %w( new_user.css )
```

Does anyone know why this could be happening? Thanks so much.

Comment: Can you please show the code of your `config/initializers/assets.rb` file (especially around line 5)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be a typo. Your code should read:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile
```

instead of:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompilerails
```